# Using IDeviceIoControl in Windows 10 for UWP

Tags: driver, win-universal-app

How can i use IDeviceIoControl  to send the data from UWP application to the driver ? I am searching for any example that does this stuff.

I found
[this link](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/DeviceIoControlUwp.htm)  which uses Win32 APIs for sending the IOCTL Commands.I am searching if there are any UWP APIS for doing this .

Comment: Having same question. Are you able to do IOCTL using DeviceIoControl?